# Adding the map canvas center to a composer label in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am able to access the map canvas center in the python console in QGIS using

```
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().center()
```

What I would like to do is get this into a map composer label.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Got it working now using this user-defined function.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

@qgsfunction(args=0, group='Custom', usesgeometry=True)
def mapCenter(value1,feature, parent):
        point = iface.mapCanvas().extent().center().toString()
        return point
```